# MS Access: The expression you entered is too complex

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to call this VBA function in the following update query and I'm getting this error. I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. The function signature seems ok to me.

[image]

`Compute([ep].[ReferenceNumber],[ep].[ITU3Number],[ep].[AuthorizationNumber],[ep].[Ent],[ep].[Indicator],[ep].[LineCode],[ep].[ProductLinee],[ep].[Inp_ProfitCenterCode],[ep].[Inp_ParisBOCode],[ep].[StartDate],[ep].[EndDate],[ep].[ExtractionDate],[ep].[OffBalance],[ep].[IType],[ep].[Counterparty],[ep].[WAL],[ep].[Inp_BackupLineIndicator],[ep].[Indicator],[ep].[FinalRating],[ep].[Amount],[ep].[Currency],[ep].[Historical],[ep].[rice],[ep].[MaturityIndicator],[ep].[pproachType],[ep].[SignatureDate],[ep].[IMaturityDate],[ep].[ProductType],[ep].[Inp_StepupDuration],[ep].[ProbabilityOfStepup],[ep].[SCF],[ep].[ICollateralSCF],[ep].[MobilFlag,[ep].[MarginBp],[ep].[ExtensionCode],[ep].[ExtensionYear],[ep].[UsageType],"a","a")`

Comment: I'm not sure there is a Compute function. Did you perhaps truncate the name?

Comment: Yeah for the sake of confidentiality! Just assume it's the same..

Comment: best not put it in the screenshot then!

Answer (score 2):

The expression is too long for Access to process:

<s>The maximum acceptable length appears to be around 560 characters</s> The maximum number of arguments seems to be 29.

For example, by truncating some fields, this works:

`Compute([ep].[ReferenceNumber],[ep].[ITU3Number],[ep].[AuthorizationNumber],[ep].[Ent],[ep].[Indicator],[ep].[LineCode],[ep].[ProductLinee],[ep].[Inp_ProfitCenterCode],[ep].[Inp_ParisBOCode],[ep].[StartDate],[ep].[EndDate],[ep].[ExtractionDate],[ep].[OffBalance],[ep].[IType],[ep].[Counterparty],[ep].[WAL],[ep].[Inp_BackupLineIndicator],[ep].[Indicator],[ep].[FinalRating],[ep].[Amount],[ep].[Currency],[ep].[Historical],[ep].[rice],[ep].[MaturityIndicator],[ep].[pproachType],[ep].[SignatureDate],[ep].[IMaturityDate],[ep].[ProductType],[ep].[Inp_StepupDuration])`

This works:

`Compute(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29)`

But this fails:

`Compute(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)`

So, you could do something like this:

`Compute(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,SubCompute(29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56))`

Comment: Let me try.. tnx. though I'm not sure if it's possible to call a function in as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, you can use function *return values* as parameters. VBA will evaluate the inner function and pass the results to the outer function. And because it's VBA you can return arrays and other objects that you can't easily pass from Access SQL.